# General purpose of jenkins nologin unix user

Tags: jenkins

I've installed Jenkins from repository for Red Hat 7. 
*sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
yum install jenkins*

And got a very simple question - after install we have system user jenkins:

**jenkins:x:956:967:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false**

1. What is general purpose of this user? (i know that  it's running Jenkins Instance) That's all what it for?

Never thought about.. and no any search answer. :)

2. If I'm changing it to login user and changing password etc., What it can affect? Any future behavior/issues of the jenkins server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is basically a service/daemon i.e similar to lots of other services which doesn't actually needs a shell to run like apache sendmail etc.

Try comparing it with other services by doing `cat /etc/passwd` on your system.

Jenkins uses the user `jenkins` to manage permissions & segregation between services like other services do.

Jenkins by default uses `sh` shell to execute your shell commands defined in your build jobs.

In case you really want to login using `jenkins` user & perform operations, give it a shell by running below command -
 `usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins`

Comment: Thank you..  I need deep understanding  (maybe from some whitepaper) of user "jenkins"  .. what permissions it has and why so?